# How to prevent power query changing formatting

Tags: excel, formatting, office365, powerquery

I have formatted tabled following loading them from power query however after the data is refreshed, some of the formatting changes. How can I prevent power query from changing any formatting whilst still updating the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to do it. You can remove table colored formatting only. Save results on the other sheet and link to the values by formulas: vlookup or index/match. Or you can save sheet results as csv and link to them via macro etc.

Comment: Thanks. Crazy that this isn't easily achievable.